# npm install causes error in fresh laravel 7 project

Tags: npm, npm-install, laravel-7

I have installed a Laravel 7.29 framework using composer. After that when I try to install node packages using `npm install`, I get the following error:

```
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...lus-loader":"^1.4.0",'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-08T12_58_03_608Z-debug.log
```

Here is my packages.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"
    }
}
```

What is the problem with my fresh Laravel project?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Did you take a look at `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-08T12_58_03_608Z-debug.log` as the message suggests? Might be a temporary error. Do you have enough disk space?

Comment: I have enough disk space. Last few lines of log file:
`1456 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
1457 verbose node v15.3.0
1458 verbose npm  v6.14.9
1459 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...lus-loader":"^1.4.0",'
1460 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`